# Как добавить в Rails приложение разделение полномочий между участниками без создания аутентификации?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Зачастую бывают такие ситуации, когда необходимо добавить своему приложению функции администрирования, при этом не создавая системы аутентификации.
Предположим, я создал блог (да, так тривиально). Просматривать список статей, читать статьи, создавать и просматривать комментарии имеют право все пользователи: и гости, и администрация, и частые посетители - все-все-все. Но вот создавать статьи, удалять их, удалять и редактировать комментарии имеют право только админы.
Как организовать данную структуру? Первым делом в голову приходит http-basic-authetication, но я не думаю, что это то, что следует использовать в реальном приложении. Тогда можно было бы создать простую систему аутентификации. Но зачем? Людям нет никакого смысла регистрироваться на блоге, если они итак могут читать посты.
Собственно, отсюда вопрос: Как грамотно построить такую систему? Добавить только модель Admin и в роуты добавить namespce admin? Или как?
Интересует, как наиболее правильно решаются такого рода задачи. Спасибо.

Comment: встраивайте любую систему авторизации, тот же devise. Если человек залогинен - показывайте ему то, что соотвествует его правам. Если нет - показывайте гостевое. Более того, не объязательно что бы форма регистрации была "общедоступна".

Comment: Вы не хотите аутентификацию, но при этом хотите опознавать некоторых посетителей? Вы уж определитесь, потому что сейчас это выглядит, как "хочу А и не-А".

Comment: @D-side я пытаюсь узнать, есть ли какие-то альтернативные способы для решения этой задачи. Или все же придется делать аутентификацию, но ограничивать ее от простых пользователей?

Comment: Аутентификация по определению это опознание посетителей. Поэтому если вы хотите кому-то давать больше прав, чем остальным, аутентификация **необходима** и стоит вопрос лишь о том, **какая именно**, а выбор большой.

Comment: @D-side примерно это я и хотел услышать.

Comment: @D-side кстати, про какой выбор идет речь? Между тем, как ее организовать, или вы про какие-то готовые решения?

Comment: Про всё. Способов аутентификации несколько (HTTP basic, токен в куках, токен в запросах, клиентский SSL и т. д.), готовых решений для некоторых из них тоже больше одного.